# Pig Latin Translate (Sentence)

Tags: java, arrays, translate

I am making a Pig Latin translator and I don't really knwo where to go from here. I have the basic code, but I need to revise it in order for it to translate a whole sentence. If anyone can tell me how to use my String[] words I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.print("Please enter a phrase to translate: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();  
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    String answer = "";
    if (str.startsWith("a") || str.startsWith("e") || str.startsWith("i") || str.startsWith("o") || str.startsWith("u"))
    {
      System.out.print(str + "way");
      }
    else
      {
        answer = str.substring(2,str.length());
        String answer2 = str.substring(1,str.length());
        String answer3 = str.substring(3,str.length());
        String answer4 = str.substring(4,str.length());
        String d = str.substring(0,4);
        if (!(d.contains("a") || d.contains("e") || d.contains("i") || d.contains("o") || d.contains("u")))
          {
            System.out.print(answer4 + d + "ay");
            }
        else 
        {
            String c = str.substring(0,3);
            if (!(c.contains("a") || c.contains("e") || c.contains("i") || c.contains("o") || c.contains("u")))
          {
            System.out.print(answer3 + c + "ay");
            }
            else
            {
                String b = str.substring(0,2);
                if (!(b.contains("a") || b.contains("e") || b.contains("i") || b.contains("o") || b.contains("u")))
                {
                    System.out.print(answer + b + "ay");
                    }
                else
                {
                    String a = str.substring(0,1);
                    if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
                    {
                        System.out.print(answer2 + a + "ay");
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For the sake of clarification, can you define your design of pig latin?

Comment: Basically if any of the first four letters of a word are consonsants, add them to the back with "ay." If the word begins with a vowel, add "way" to the end of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should translate each word in that array, just use a for loop around your whole if block

```
for(String word: words) {
   //put your whole if block here
   //word is the variable to translate (i.e. word.startsWith("a"))
}
```

alternatively for beginners:

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
  //put if statements here
  //words[i] is the variable to translate (i.e. words[i].startsWith("a"))
}
```

You will also need to change all `str` references inside the loop to `word[i]`, since that is the variable you want to use.

Comment: I used the alternative method but I ran into a slight problem. I'm headed in the right direction, but now it will only translate up to four words. Does this have to do with the fact that I have String answer4 = words[i].substring94,words[i].length())? How might I make it loop infinitely until a blank space?

Comment: right now you have a list of words, and this loop will go through every one of those items one at a time.  Not sure what you're asking.  Feel free too add code to your question and I'll take a look @Gihadi

Comment: @Gihadi if it is translating 4 words correctly then this should be a very simple fix, let me know what's going wrong

Comment: Gihadi, I do not know java well; does it have support for Regular Expressions? If so, that may work better, rather than looping through each letter. 

You state the rule is, "Basically if any of the first four letters of a word are consonsants, add them to the back with "ay." If the word begins with a vowel, add "way" to the end of the word. " So, Amsterdam would be Amsterdamway; Niederlande would be iederlandeNay; Stephan would be ephanStay? 

If java has regular expression support, you may be able to get the portion from beginning to first consonant and append it at the end.

Comment: It is not translating everything up to four words, but I think the problem is because not all words are starting with the same amount of consonants and the code makes it only translate words of the same beginning, how do you think I can fix that. I'll try to upload the code to show you.

Comment: @Gihadi are you sure you changed all the `str.` to `words[i].`?

Comment: I finally fixed the code, but I just need to know how to find the legnth of an individual word in words[i]. Obviously something like words[i].length doesn't work, do you know how to do that?

Comment: words[i].length() @Gihadi

Comment: Thanks a whole lot, this really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a for loop that goes through each word, and apply your logic to each word:

```
for(String str : words ) {

    if (str.startsWith("a") || str.startsWith("e") || str.startsWith("i") || str.startsWith("o") || str.startsWith("u"))
    {
        System.out.print(str + "way");
    }
    else
    {
        answer = str.substring(2,str.length());
        String answer2 = str.substring(1,str.length());
        String answer3 = str.substring(3,str.length());
        String answer4 = str.substring(4,str.length());
        String d = str.substring(0,4);
        if (!(d.contains("a") || d.contains("e") || d.contains("i") || d.contains("o") || d.contains("u")))
        {
            System.out.print(answer4 + d + "ay");
        }
        else 
        {
            String c = str.substring(0,3);
            if (!(c.contains("a") || c.contains("e") || c.contains("i") || c.contains("o") || c.contains("u")))
            {
                System.out.print(answer3 + c + "ay");
            }
            else
            {
                String b = str.substring(0,2);
                if (!(b.contains("a") || b.contains("e") || b.contains("i") || b.contains("o") || b.contains("u")))
                {
                    System.out.print(answer + b + "ay");
                }
                else
                {
                    String a = str.substring(0,1);
                    if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
                    {
                        System.out.print(answer2 + a + "ay");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enhanced for loop around your *if* block to translate the entire array:

```
for(String word: words) {
  /*
   *if block goes here
   *...
   */ 
}
```

Though creating a translator like this is rather unsafe (e.g. code injections), unless the input is put in from a trusted source.

If you are familiar with lexer/parsers you should look into using a generator such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to create safer (albeight more complex) language translators.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include stdio.h>
#include conio.h>
#include stdlib.h>
#include string.h>

void main()
{
       char *  sUserInput ;
       char *  check      ;
       char *  firstletter;

       char    ch    = NULL;
       int     i          = 0   ;
       int     j          = 0   ;
       int     k          = 0   ;
       int     spacecount = 0   ;
       int     count      = 0   ;
       int     count1     = 0   ;
       int     var        = 0   ;
       int     gold       = 1   ;

       sUserInput  = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
       check       = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
       firstletter = (char *) malloc(4*sizeof(char));

       printf("Enter the sentence \n");

       while(ch != '\n')
       {
             scanf("%c",&ch);
             sUserInput[i]=ch;
             sUserInput = (char *) realloc(sUserInput,((i+2))*sizeof(char));
             i++;
             if( ch == ' ')
             {
                 spacecount++;
             }
       }

       while(sUserInput[j] != '\n')
       {
             count1++;
             if(gold==1)
             {
                    firstletter[var]=sUserInput[j];
                    firstletter[var+1]='a';
                    firstletter[var+2]='y';
                    gold=0;
                    j++;
             }
             if(sUserInput[j] !=' ')
             {
                    check[k] = sUserInput[j];
                    check = (char *) realloc(check,((k+2))*sizeof(char));
                    printf("%c",check[k]);
                    k++;
             }
             if(sUserInput[j] ==' ' || (count1 == (i-(spacecount+2))))
             {
                    for(count=0;count<3;count++)
                    {
                           printf("%c",firstletter[count]);
                    }
                    var=0;
                    gold=1;
                    printf(" ");
             }
             j++;
       }

       free(sUserInput);
       free(check);
       free(firstletter);
       getch();
}
```